# Line break after hyphen

Tags: html, css, firefox

When running the following snippet on FF 45, the first of the two boxes only shows one single line like "ThisIsATest...", while the second box shows two lines whith the whole text divided by the hyphen. On Chrome and Edge, both boxes show two lines. My question: How can I make the text in the first one break after the hyphen in FF? Obviously, it has something to do with the length of the following text but what is the reason for that?

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test
</div>

<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test123
</div>
```

I want to achieve this behavior (which already works in Chrome and Edge) : If the text doesn't include any hyphens or whitespaces, do not break it and show the "...".
If the text includes a whitespace or hyphen, break it if necessary.

**Update:**

You can remove text-overflow: ellipsis and get a similar result. Now, the text is sometimes cut off, sometimes there will be a new line. I do not see any reason why two similar divs (one with a little more content) should show such a different behavior.

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;  
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test
</div>

<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test123
</div>
```

In FF 45.0.1 on Windows 10, it currently looks like this:

[image: Text sometimes getting cut-off, sometimes jumping into a new line]

Comment: The behavior in Firefox is correct. Chrome, for some reason, is not displaying the ellipsis as it should. But that's not the overall problem, I know.

Comment: Why can the behavior in FF be considered correct if it sometimes shows a new line and sometimes not? This doesn't look very consistent to me...

Comment: You specify the overflow to be ellipsis. Firefox is doing that while Chrome is not. I'm not sure you want that at all.

Comment: I updated the question - see my new code sample. Removing text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't help. To me, it looks like a a "random" behavior. Where is the difference between these two boxes? Only its content. Why sould the text sometimes be cut off at the edge and sometimes (after adding a few more characters) jump into the new line?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "real" hyphen (i.e. if you don't need the "-" to be displayed when everything fits in one line), you can use the "soft hyphen" entity `&shy;`:

```
ThisIsATest&shy;Test
```

Comment: I actually need the hyphen. It is just a pretty weird behavior to me: Longer text is displayed correctly (with two lines). Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the properties `word-wrap: break-word;` or `white-space: nowrap;` to your test class and both divs will produce the same behavior.

For example:

> **word-wrap:** break-word;

Will produce two lines.

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test
</div>

<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test123
</div>
```

> **white-space:** nowrap;

Will produce one line with ellipsis.

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test
</div>

<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test123
</div>
```

Comment: OK, sorry. I should have specified this a bit more. I do not want the text to be shown in one single line (that's why I created the second box - this is the "desired behavior"). I want the text to break after the hyphen. If there is no hyphen, the text should be shown in one single line. This does work in Chrome and for longer words after the hyphen in FF as well. What I don't understand: Why doesn't it work with my first example?

Comment: Updated! Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Mh, not really - sorry. The thing is: using word-wrap: break-word will break the word "randomly". I want to break the word after a whitespace or hyphen. (Just fyi: In German, we have many compounded nouns (don't know the exact translation). Instead of saying "smartphone app", we say "Smartpone-App".  So it is a bit more than having two words standing next to each other (divided by a whitespace) but in many cases it makes sense to break them at the hyphen. )

Answer (score 0):

I found this trick on this [blog](https://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/), but i don't know if will resolve your issue.

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;

  word-break: break-word;

  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test
</div>

<div class="test">
  ThisIsATest-Test123
</div>
```

Comment: Your test code breaks like this: "ThisIsATest-Te" + "st" because of word-break: break-all; Btw: word-break: break-word doesn't exist and I assume you mean word-wrap

Comment: The tag **word-break** exists but i never used it. The [specification](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) on W3.

Comment: You used word-break: break-word and I wanted to mention that it is not valid. Possible values for word-break are: normal, break-all, keep-all, initial and inherit. You used break-word which is simply not specified. Read your code again and you will see what I mean :-) I have highlighted it here: [link](http://snag.gy/9OMkT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following css property to its parent

```css
white-space: nowrap;
```